# How to require drivers during program installation?

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, windows-installer, ftdi

I have a C++ project in QT Creator meant for the Windows environment. I will create an installer for it, which the users can use to install my program on their own PC. However my program relies on the FTDI device drivers being present, which doesn't reliably happen when the USB device (with which the program communicates) gets plugged in.

I don't want the users to have to go to a site and install a driver themselves. Is there a way I can "bundle" the driver installation with my installer such that this all happens in one workflow for the consumer?

Comment: What's the problem in downloading the driver installation, incorporating in your installer and launching it as part of the installation process?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot figure out how to do this

Comment: I don't know QT Creator, but if it can't do the job then you need another installer. There are many.

Comment: Thanks for at least confirming that this is possible. I would still really appreciate if someone can detail how.

Comment: You could have a look at [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and [its alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/inno-setup/).